# Parsing of Wide Characters String in C

Tags: c, winapi

I wanted to store arguments that passed to my program from the command line and then forward them to a function which it needs all strings to have wchar_t data format. In the following program, I have commented the function and use printf to test the program but the following function doesn't work. Where is the problem:

```
int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR* cp_UserName[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR* cp_DomainName[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR* cp_HashNtlm[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR* cp_ComputerName[MAX_PATH];

    DnPthIconSetup();
    DnPthInitialization(TRUE);

    int counter = argc;

    if (argc > 4)
    {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (!_tcsnccmp(argv[i], L"user:", 5))
            {
                *cp_UserName = _tcschr(argv[i], L':') + 1;
            }
            if (!_tcsnccmp(argv[i], L"domain:", 7))
            {
                *cp_DomainName = _tcschr(argv[i], L':') + 1;
            }
            if (!_tcsnccmp(argv[i], L"pc:", 3))
            {
                *cp_ComputerName = _tcschr(argv[i], L':') + 1;
            }
            if (!_tcsnccmp(argv[i], L"ntlm:", 5))
            {
                *cp_HashNtlm = _tcschr(argv[i], L':') + 1;
            }
        }

        wprintf("%s\n", *cp_UserName);
        wprintf("%s\n", *cp_DomainName);
        wprintf("%s\n", *cp_ComputerName);
        wprintf("%s\n", *cp_HashNtlm);
        system("PAUSE");
        // ParametricCredentialDispatcher(cp_UserName, cp_DomainName, cp_HashNtlm, cp_ComputerName);
    }
    else if (argc == 1)
    {
        InteractiveMode();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nUsage: ./program user:[] domain:[] pc:[] ntlm:[]\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Where is the problem"* - Right here: `int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])`. Make that `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])` and call it a day.

Comment: @IInspectable Can you put the correct code as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    wchar_t* cp_UserName = NULL;
    wchar_t* cp_DomainName = NULL;
    wchar_t* cp_HashNtlm = NULL;
    wchar_t* cp_ComputerName = NULL;

    DnPthIconSetup();
    DnPthInitialization(TRUE);

    int counter = argc;

    if (argc > 4)
    {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (!wcsncmp(argv[i], L"user:", 5))
            {
                cp_UserName = argv[i] + 5;
            }
            else if (!wcsncmp(argv[i], L"domain:", 7))
            {
                cp_DomainName = argv[i] + 7;
            }
            else if (!wcsncmp(argv[i], L"pc:", 3))
            {
                cp_ComputerName = argv[i] + 3;
            }
            else if (!wcsncmp(argv[i], L"ntlm:", 5))
            {
                cp_HashNtlm = argv[i] + 5;
            }
        }

        wprintf(L"%s\n", cp_UserName);
        wprintf(L"%s\n", cp_DomainName);
        wprintf(L"%s\n", cp_ComputerName);
        wprintf(L"%s\n", cp_HashNtlm);
        system("PAUSE");
        // ParametricCredentialDispatcher(cp_UserName, cp_DomainName, cp_HashNtlm, cp_ComputerName);
    }
    else if (argc == 1)
    {
        InteractiveMode();
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"\nUsage: ./program user:[] domain:[] pc:[] ntlm:[]\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of pointer

```
TCHAR* cp_UserName[MAX_PATH];
```

I'm sure you meant an array of characters, which would be

```
TCHAR cp_UserName[MAX_PATH];
```